# Mi sitio web Joomla no ejecuta el index.php y en vez de mostrar el contenido del sitio al acceder al dominio, descarga el archivo index.php

Tags: php, joomla3

Al ingresar al sitio web me descarga el index.php en vez de mostrarme el contenido del sitio. Estoy utilizando joomla y este es el contenido del index.

```
<?php

define('JOOMLA_MINIMUM_PHP', '5.3.10');

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, JOOMLA_MINIMUM_PHP, '<'))
{
die('Your host needs to use PHP ' . JOOMLA_MINIMUM_PHP . ' or higher to run 
this version of Joomla!');
}

// Saves the start time and memory usage.
$startTime = microtime(1);
$startMem  = memory_get_usage();


define('_JEXEC', 1);

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php'))
{
include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// Set profiler start time and memory usage and mark afterLoad in the 
profiler.
JDEBUG ? JProfiler::getInstance('Application')->setStart($startTime, 
$startMem)->mark('afterLoad') : null;

// Instantiate the application.
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// Execute the application.
$app->execute();

?>
```

Comment: Soy nuevo en este foro, lo inserté completo pero no se porque aparece reducido.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta, creo que ya puedes visualizar con mas detalle el error que me muestra el index.php que descarga mi equipo cuando decido acceder al sitio desde su direccion de dominio para visualizar el contenido.

Answer (score 1):

tiene pinta de que no esta funcionando php, yo empezaría mirando si te carga algo como...

archivoDePrueba.php

`<?php echo "hola";?>`

Comment: Así es, no está funcionando php unicamente con ese sitio en el servidor.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no has configurado correctamente Apache para poder usar PHP.

Si usas Linux y Apache2 deberías tener en el directorio **/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/** los siguientes ficheros

> /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf
>
> /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load

Comment: No existe ese directorio en el servidor que estoy trabajando

Comment: Empecemos por lo inicial... ¿Que Sistema Operativo tienen el servidor? ¿Tienes instalado Apache y PHP? ¿Tienes instalado LAMP/WAMP/XAMP?

Comment: CENTOS 6.9 xen, se tiene instalado Apache/2.4.29 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2m, versiones de php ea-php54, 55, 56, 70